# A string variable has more length than the actual file

Tags: c#, string, streamreader

I'm working on [Problem #8 from Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8).

The goal is to parse a very large number which consists of 1000 digits, but for some reason my program always displays an 1038 digit number.

The number is:

```
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

Here is what I have:

```
StreamReader read=new StreamReader(@"Practise.txt");
string str=read.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
```

Comment: Did you count the line endings?

Comment: +2 characters per line end

Comment: @Slai what are these characters?

Comment: `"\r"` and `"\n"`, but you can just `string str = string.Concat(File.ReadAllLines("Practise.txt"));`

Comment: but it's not clear if vertical adjacent counts too, or if it has to be 1 line

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your file has line breaks, which you don't want.

You can use this code instead:

```
var str = string.Concat(File.ReadLines(fileName));
```